# XenServer 6.2 KVMoIP remote install - Won't boot into install

Tags: linux, boot, xen

I've had my hosting provider download and burn me a CD/DVD of XenServer 6.2 twice now and it is still not booting properly.

I get so far as to reach a 'boot:' prompt with a number of installation options but when I hit enter to boot into the normal installation wizard, I end up with:

```
boot:
EDD: Error 8000 reading sector 259047
mboot.c32: not a COM32R image
```

Any idea what this could be or how I can get around it? I can't find much about this at all on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

So, try replace mboot.c32 with an older version and see if it works.

it mount by USB disk and replace the `mboot.c32`, and run the syslinux command on it.

```
cp -r /usr/lib/syslinux/mboot.c32 /media/disk/boot/syslinux/ 
syslinux /dev/sdb1
```